# HTML Form naming conventions

Tags: html, forms, laravel, conventions

If I have an HTML form with two inputs that would insert/modify a columns with the same name in two tables in a database.
What would be the best way to name my input elements?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothers_name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Mothers Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="childs_name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Child's Name">
</div>
```

db-
--table1
---name
--table2
--name

I am trying to save these information using laravels create(request->all())

I see that the request object contains the last input value.

Comment: can i name the second input as table2_name and laravel will know that to save that to the second table? <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothers_name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Mothers Name">
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="childs_name" name="table2_name" placeholder="Enter Child's Name">
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

I would name the inputs the same way you have named the ids. (Or something similar.)

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothers_name" name="mothers_name" placeholder="Enter Mother's Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="childs_name" name="childs_name" placeholder="Enter Child's Name">
</div>
```

Within your Controller, you could do something like this:

```
public function storeNameTable1(Request $request) {
    $store_name = new Table1;
    $store_name->name = $request->mothers_name;
    $store_name->save();
}

public function storeNameTable2(Request $request) {
    $store_name = new Table2;
    $store_name->name = $request->childs_name;
    $store_name->save();
}
```

Comment: If both tables have a column with the same name e.g: "nickname" how would I name my form inputs? because I think if i do Laravel's mass assignment create the request()->all() would translate to an array combining inputs with the same name.

Comment: If there are always 2 in the same order, you could add them to an array like this: **name="name[]"** and then access them in your Controller this way: **$request->name[0]** (for mother's name) and **$request->name[1]** for the child's name.